# EXCEL/VBA: converting boolean text to checks

Tags: vba, excel

I've exported data from access to excel.
Some columns where boolean values, and excel displays them as "true" or "false".
Not very readable, so I want to change the false values to blank, and the true values to "x".

Here is the VBA code I wrote:

```
Sub BoolToCheck()
Dim myRow As Integer
Dim myCol As Integer

For myCol = 7 To 38
    For myRow = 2 To 458

    Select Case Cells(myRow, myCol)
        Case "TRUE"
         Cells(myRow, myCol) = "x"
        Case "FALSE"
         Cells(myRow, myCol) = ""
    End Select

    DoEvents
    Next myRow
Next myCol
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work; when I'm running it step by step, neither case happens.
tried switching from "true" and "false" to true and false, but it didn't change anything.

Anyone knows why this isn't working ?  I don't get it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using .Text is dangerous because it reads the formatted value of the cell, which might be ### if the user has reduced the column widths.
True and False are handled as Boolean values rather than text/strings so this code works:

```
Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k)
    Case True
       ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k) = "x"
    Case False
       ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k) = ""
 End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub MarkTrue()

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("G2:AR458").Cells
        If rCell.Value = True Then
            rCell.Value = "X"
        ElseIf rCell.Value = False Then
            rCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Another method using For Each and no Select Case, both of which should be faster.  Although I'll defer to Charles Williams whether that's true.

Answer (score 0):

changed from

```
Select Case Cells(myRow, myCol)
```

to

```
Select Case Cells(myRow, myCol).text
```

works now.